# Python sorted() or its alternative to get/return resulting key lambda value by which it was sorted

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

Suppose I have a dictionary/list/anything. I am sorting this set according to some function (not directly dependent on the value, square is given as an example):

```
dict_a = {('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)}

def temp(x):
    return x**2

print(sorted(dict_a, key=lambda item:temp(item[1])))
```

Is there any way/syntax to get/return the value of the key obtained from a call to lambda (by which the resulting list was sorted), in order not to calculate it twice later, e.g.:

```
[(1, ('c', 1)), (4, ('b', 2)), (9, ('a', 3))]
```

rather than

```
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

Preferably in a single line of code and only standard libraries. Does Python have capability to do that? Thanks!

Comment: you have to do this manually, there's no such functionality in `sorted`

Comment: You say "dict", but you've written a set of tuples.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I meant to say any sortable set in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could already `map` it before sorting:

```
>>> sorted(map(lambda x: (temp(x[1]), x), dict_a))
[(1, ('c', 1)), (4, ('b', 2)), (9, ('a', 3))]
>>>
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
>>> sorted([(temp(x[1]), x) for x in dict_a])
[(1, ('c', 1)), (4, ('b', 2)), (9, ('a', 3))]
>>>
```

Comment: @TernaryStripe Your welcome :) Happy coding!

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode For that case just do `sorted([(temp(x[1]), x) for x in dict_a], key=lambda x: x[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Just do the transform beforehand and sort that:

```
dict_a = {('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)}

def temp(x):
    return x**2

expected = [(1, ('c', 1)), (4, ('b', 2)), (9, ('a', 3))]
transformed = [(temp(item[1]), item) for item in dict_a]
assert sorted(transformed) == expected
```

Note that you typoed `('c', 3)` in your question and that `dict_a` is not a dict, but a set of tuples..

Comment: Um... that gives AssertionError.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect to get two answers that fast.